# Which one is preferred to write x-axis as a single unit that cannot be hyphenated?

Tags: best-practices

Which one is preferred to write x-axis as a single unit that cannot be hyphenated by LaTeX?

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\preview
Along the $x\text{-axis}$,
\endpreview

\preview
Along the \mbox{$x$-axis},
\endpreview
\end{document}
```

As a completeness, I don't think

```
Along the $x$-axis,
```

is recommended because hyphenation may sometimes occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the options are equivalent output-wise, so the question is about a semantic choice.

In my opinion then, the answer is the same as for all compound words containing math elements : they are words you use in an english sentence, not in a math formula. So the latter option would make more sense.

And since I'm lazy, I wouldn't bother writing `\mbox{...}` all the time, I would just add it in the final version of the document where needed.

Answer (score 6):

Let me note that there is not any typographical rule that states that the below method is any way correct. It can merely be used if one wishes to control the dash's placement.

One way to do this is to add a command which adds a non-hyphenated dash.

This can be done with `\nobreakdash`. However, this will not allow any hyphenation until the next word (i.e. no hyphenation in the *axis* word). Thus one should add a space which breaks the words

A solution would be

```
% Requires amsmath package
\def\dirdash{\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}}
```

This will show this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,amsmath}
\geometry{paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=6cm,textheight=3cm,textwidth=4cm}
\def\dirdash#1{\nobreakdash#1\hspace{0pt}}
\begin{document}
Hello, this is the a $x$-axis

Hello, this is the a $x$\dirdash-axis

Hello, this is the a $x$-longword

Hello, this is the a $x$\dirdash-longword
\end{document}
```

And yield the following output

[image]

Comment: Preventing hyphenation in compound words is the default behavior, even without `\nobreakdash`. See for example this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-to-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash . You may want to bypass this from time to time, but I would disadvise making it a global setting.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean? Maybe, I have misinterpreted the request. I would not use this `\dirdash` on every dash. It seemed that it was only requested at the mathematical descriptors `$x$-<something>`?

Comment: Even in mathematical descriptors. I'm no typographist, so I follow blindly the typographical rules, as much as possible. If latex does not want to add an hyphen in the middle of "axis", I don't think it's a good idea to bypass this "safety measure" every time one uses the expression "$x$-axis". Instead, I'd suggest to add `\-` at the wanted hyphenation point in `$x$-<somethinglong>`, only when needed.

Comment: I agree, that typographically speaking there is nothing wrong with `$x$-\linebreak axis`. Yes, but I can also see the clarity imposed when forcing that a linebreak must not be put at the `-`, just as you would for `Eq.~(2.1)`. For the word `<somethinglong>` it should of course not be limited, why the `\hspace{0pt}` allows hyphenation of that word.

Comment: Why "of course"? Try it in a real document, having two hyphens (one dash and one end-of-line hyphen) in the same word definitely looks weird to me. See for example : http://i.imgur.com/dY5bGxJ.png . Once again, from time to time, it's still a better choice than an overfull hbox. But for the default setting, I still prefer to let latex try to play with its glues and stretchable spaces as hard as it can, before it tells me I *have* to force the hyphenation.

Comment: Yes, great, example. I think we agree, that generally any hyphenation should not be controlled. I simply added a way to control it (in the way that @GarbageCollector seemed to request).

Comment: `\nobreakdash` serves no purpose, if you add `\hspace{0pt}` after the hyphen, that introduces a feasible line break point; you probably meant `\nobreakdash-\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}`, but then `\mbox{-}` would be more efficient than `\nobreakdash-`

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by this, so, `\nobreakdash` does not affect the word hyphenation of the coming word? Is my examples then coincidences of the penalty not kicking in? I thought that the `\hspace` simply allowed for word hyphenation of the following word? If you are right (and to my knowledgde @egreg is ALWAYS correct :), would you then please elaborate about the examples I provided?) then numerous websites are wrong.

Comment: @zeroth I may be incorrect, some times. ;-) But `\mbox{-}` is surely more efficient than `\nobreakdash-`; `\nobreakdash` looks forward to see if another `-` follows and you don't need it.

Comment: @egreg, ok, so `\mbox` works because the words are glued together, with no allowed hyphenation on the immediate left/right sides of the dash?. But why does my `x\nobreakdash-longword` then not hyphenate at `long-\linebreak word`?

Comment: @zeroth It's a word that isn't considered for hyphenation past the hyphen. With `\hspace{0pt}` you allow again searching for hyphenation, but remember to precede it by `\nolinebreak` (or simply `\nobreak`).